# Bug in label for legend with beamer, tikz, animate

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, animate

I am very puzzled by this small bug. This example does not work because compilation crashes on the line containing `\label{Temp\iIdPic}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{mwe}
\begin{animateinline}[]{3}
\multiframe{4}{iIdPic=1+1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\begin{axis}[ytick=\empty,xmin=0,xmax=5,hide x axis]
\addplot+[mark=none] {3*x+\iIdPic};
\label{Temp\iIdPic}
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[ytick=\empty,xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=1,xlabel={Time (s)},%
        legend cell align=left,legend style={at={(axis description cs:1.0,1.05)},anchor=south east}]
\draw[gray,ultra thin] (axis cs:\iIdPic,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- %
        (axis cs:\iIdPic,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Temp\iIdPic}\addlegendentry{problem}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I want to do: Have an animation where the grey line is passing through the graph. The crashing bug is to have the legends correctly set-up. If you remove the line `\label{Temp\iIdPic}`, it compiles fine but in the legend the line identifying the referenced line is not of the correct colour.

---

Even though it does NOT solve the problem, I have narrowed down the problem to being an incompatibility between `\label` and the `animateinline` environnement.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{mwe}
\begin{animateinline}[]{3}
    \label{Temp};
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Also, you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: This seems to me a: _May I complicate something? Yes, I can!_ solution. I suppose `\foreach \step in {1,2,3,4}{
\begin{axis}[options]
  \draw<\step>[gray,ultra thin] (axis cs:\step,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:\step,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}); 
\end{axis}
}` would work.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino It will but it is not what I need unfortunately. I would like to create an animation that I can click on to launch.

Comment: @AlexG Argh, nevermind. I'm just being stupid. I thought that was the text label now I see that it's the variable name. I'm deleting my idiotic comments

Comment: @Rufus: Your second, reduced code example works in the standard `article` class. Thus, is it rather a `beamer` related problem?

Comment: Please rephrase your question/make it more clear (especially the title): Bug reports are off-topic here, questions for bug workarounds are on topic. Perhaps this isn’t a bug, though? (I cannot judge this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an email exchange with Christian Feuersanger from the `pgfplots` package and he gave me a work around. Here it is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}

\let\XXXlabel=\label
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{mwe}
\begin{animateinline}[]{3}
\multiframe{4}{iIdPic=1+1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\let\label=\XXXlabel
\begin{axis}[ytick=\empty,xmin=0,xmax=5,hide x axis]
\addplot+[mark=none] {3*x+\iIdPic};
\label{Temp\iIdPic}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```